# Issue aligning footer page selector to center in less using media queries

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, media-queries, kendo-grid

I am trying to make the page selector of the grid which in the footer to center. But no property is aligning that to center. As per requirement I can not use margin as I am using responsive screen
I used display:inline-block but no use.
(This happened after doing kendo upgrade)
Can anyone help me with this issue using media queries.

```
@media all and (max-width :400px) 
 {
  .pager-sizes
    {
      display:inline-block;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you are on, but currently the pager is using a flexbox layout. So you can prepend an element with the `k-spacer` class that is used to separate items in toolbars. For the latest version it does the trick:

`$(".k-grid-pager").prepend('<div class="k-spacer"></div>')`

Here is an [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/akicULas).